# Поиск дубликатов текстовых записей

Tags: php, mysql

Есть база данных с текстовым полем, в котором хранятся собственно говоря посты (от 0 до нескольких кб длиной). Мне нужно найти все дубликаты текстов в этой колонке и пометить их специальным флагом (для флага я выбрал отдельное поле).

Я придумал такой алгоритм, но очень не уверен в его оптимальности с точки зрения ресурсозатрат:

1. выбираю один пост с пустым флагом.
2. С помощью конструкции

   ```
   SELECT id, data, MATCH (data) AGAINST
        (?s) AS score FROM table WHERE ?p ORDER BY score DESC, id DESC LIMIT 0, 1000
   ```

   я выбираю посты, упорядоченные по степени соответствия с первым.
3. первый из этой 1000 я считаю релевантным на 100% (как будто бы). Но я всеравно уточняю это соответствие с помощью php функции similar_text. Если > 90% совпадения, значит это дубликат (да, различия небольшие допускаются, это как раз то что мне нужно). Если нет, то беру следующий из этой 1000 (раньше при несовпадении по similar, я сразу останавливался и переходил к началу цикла (п1), но потом заметил, что идентичные посты могут быть вовсе даже не на первом месте (вот так вот, да, работает полнотекстовый поиск в mySQL, не совсем он предсказуем).
4. далее я беру следующие посты, пока вычисляемая релевантность относительно первого не упадёт до некоторого значения (score). и все их прогоняю со сравниваемым через similar_text. То, что > 90% отмечаю.
   Далее цикл повторяется до тех пор, пока все посты не будут проверены/размечены.

Проблема в том, что это довольно долго. Но без полнотекстового поиска match-against, одним similar - это еще дольше, даже и думать нечего, а без similar - можно нахватать совершенно левых дубликатов.

Может быть у кого то есть соображения, как улучшить сей алгоритм?
Скорость этого моего алгоритма зависит от размера базы: при 500 000 записей (постов), обработка одного занимает десятки секунд.

Comment: *нужно найти все дубликаты текстов* Крайне желательно чётко обозначить критерии "дубликатости". Ибо зацикливаться на MATCH > 0.9 - это безальтернативно ограничить себя FTS. Который, впрочем, можно заменить каким-нить внешним движком, типа эластика.

Comment: критерий php функции similar_text >90% -это как раз то что нужно мне. Но я не могу ею сравнивать каждый пост с каждым, это очень долго. Поэтому я предварительно выбираю посты для такого сравнения с помощью SQL MATCH-AGAINST. Но вот всеравно получается долговато...